# flask-socketio will occasionally disconnect from rooms and fail to reconnect.

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, eventlet

I am running a flask-socketio application with eventlet where all sockets emit to specific rooms. Each room representing a chat area with the room name being the chat_uuid from a flask-sqlalchemy table. Users will enter chat rooms when they get into the chat page of the application. I am running this application both locally and on an AWS ec2 with NGINX and Gunicorn. The error is that users are occasionally unable to receive messages. For example, I have opened 40-50 chrome tabs and have sent a message and only 1 tab has failed to receive the message.  At first, I thought this error was related to this stack trace I got in the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 539, in handle_one_response
result = self.application(self.environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 47, in __call__
return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 360, in handle_request
return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/server.py", line 274, in handle_request
environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 91, in handle_get_request
start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 133, in _upgrade_websocket
return ws(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/async_eventlet.py", line 19, in __call__
return super(WebSocketWSGI, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 129, in __call__
self.handler(ws)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 158, in _websocket_handler
pkt = ws.wait()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 787, in wait
for i in self.iterator:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 642, in _iter_frames
message = self._recv_frame(message=fragmented_message)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 668, in _recv_frame
header = recv(2)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line 577, in _get_bytes
d = self.socket.recv(numbytes - len(data))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 363, in recv
return self._recv_loop(self.fd.recv, b'', bufsize, flags)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 357, in _recv_loop
self._read_trampoline()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 328, in _read_trampoline
timeout_exc=socket_timeout('timed out'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py", line 207, in _trampoline
mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/__init__.py", line 163, in trampoline
return hub.switch()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 295, in switch
return self.greenlet.switch()
socket.timeout: timed out
```

I then noticed this log after the stack trace:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2018 11:46:46] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=201dbaa98d9844c998c5e94366838d24 HTTP/1.1" 500 0 60.089869
2018-04-09 11:46:46,454 - portal.api.sockets - INFO - User USERNAME has disconnected to sockets
```

So there was a socket timeout after 60 seconds, which is the default flask-socketio ping_interval time.  So in my flask-socketio init I changed my ping settings to

```
socket_io = SocketIO(
app,

...
ping_interval=2000,
ping_timeout=120000,

...)
```

And on the client side javascript I changed the socketio timeout to be larger as well:

```
socket = io.connect(location.origin, {
'timeout': 120000 // Increasing connection timeout.
})
```

This seems to reduce the error, but it still occurs. In particular it will occur more on the server than it will locally.

After some more debugging I concluded that the error has to do with users occasionally disconnecting from rooms without attempting to reconnect to these rooms. In order to confirm my suspicions, I created a debug method that joins a room. So in a browser tab with this error, I joined the room it "failed" to join with the debug function and tried sending a message to it in another window and it was received. So the error may be related to my join_room function, which is this

```
@socket_io.on('connect-to-chat-room')
def connect_to_chat(chat_uuid):
    # Join chat room and see if user is authorized to join it.
    chat_room = get_chat_by_uuid(chat_uuid)
    if is_authorized_object(chat_permission, chat_room.chat_id):
        logger.debug("Socket connection attempt to chat_uuid{}".format(chat_uuid))
        join_room(chat_uuid)
        logger.info("User {} sockets connected to chat room with uuid:{}".format(current_user.username, chat_uuid))
    else:
        return False
```

After doing some research, I noticed a github issue that explains that you must use socketio.sleep to release the CPU (https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/670). So I updated my function to have some sleep calls in order to reduce CPU usage.

```
@socket_io.on('connect-to-chat-room')
def connect_to_chat(chat_uuid):
    # Join chat room and see if user is authorized to join it.
    socket_io.sleep(0)
    chat_room = get_chat_by_uuid(chat_uuid)
    if is_authorized_object(chat_permission, chat_room.chat_id):
        socket_io.sleep(0)
        logger.debug("Socket connection attempt to chat_uuid{}".format(chat_uuid))
        join_room(chat_uuid)
        socket_io.sleep(0)
        logger.info("User {} sockets connected to chat room with uuid:{}".format(current_user.username, chat_uuid))
    else:
        socket_io.sleep(0)
        return False
```

However, this does not seem to fix the error. Another interesting tidbit I found out about this error is that after doing some browser testing it happens far more often in Safari than it does in chrome. With chrome, 1 out of 40 tabs will have the error while in safari the number is closer to 6 out of 40. I believe this is due to safari switching from websockets to longpolling though that is only a guess and I am not fully sure why that is.

Right now I am confused as to what to do next in order to solve this issue. Can anybody help?

Comment: Add logging on the Socket.IO server to see if anything interesting is shown there. Just add `engineio_logger=True` to your SocketIO class.

Comment: I have it enabled, and I am planning to post a stack trace to pastebin but the inconsistency of the bug is not allowing me at the moment. Is there anything I should be looking for in the logs?

Comment: I would look for anything that is not a sending/receiving messages. Error messages, stack traces, warnings.